# how to share and use qr code and url in expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, qr-code, react-qr-code

good evening
please help me to solve this question on qr code expo. because I have learn created the app.I wanted you to guide me so that I can start coding in this space.
[[I have the followingerror code for using URL or QR code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pddnZ.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2RLS.jpg)